# How to undo last added line in google map drawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have 2 options in my google map. 
 -->one is polygon and another one is draw lines.
Now am trying to perform undo functionality in my page.When I click `undo` button  recently added line should be removed(that may be in either polygon option or draw line option).
Is it possible?

```
 function initMap() {
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
          });

          var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
              drawingModes: ['polygon', 'polyline']
            },

            circleOptions: {
              strokeColor: '#00DB00',
              fillColor: 'green',
              fillOpacity: 0.05,
              strokeWeight: 5,
              clickable: false,
              editable: true,
              zIndex: 1
            }

          });
          drawingManager.setMap(map);
           google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (event)
            {
              if (event.type === 'marker') console.log('Lat: ' + event.overlay.position.lat() + ', Long: ' + event.overlay.position.lng())
              else displayPolyLatLng(event.overlay.getPath().b); 
            });


          function displayPolyLatLng(pointArray)
          {debugger

              var result=" ";
              for (var i = 0; i < pointArray.length; i++) 
              {
                  result +='<b>Lat: ' + pointArray[i].lat() + ', Long: ' + pointArray[i].lng()+ '</b><br/>';
              }
              $('#info').html(result); 

              /*var lastEl = pointArray[pointArray.length-1];
              alert(lastEl)
              if(lastEl.length>1){
              undo_redo.push(lastEl.pop());
              } */    
          }
      }
      function removeLine(){
        polylines.remove(polylines.size() - 1)
      }
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rc5p32nt/

Comment: I think that is not possible.new google maps are not user friendly!!

Comment: Yes it is possible.  You have to write code to keep a reference to the last shape added.

Comment: @krish it's possible, see my answer below if you're interested

Answer (score 4):

Basically what @geocodezip said...

Keep a reference to the shapes added:

```
var overlays = [];
```

You can then push the latest overlay object `event.overlay` in the `overlaycomplete` event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
   overlays.push(event.overlay); // store reference to added overlay
});
```

Finally, on click of the Undo button hide the overlay via `setMap(null)`:

```
// undo last overlay action
function removeLine() {
  var lastOverlay = overlays.pop();
  if (lastOverlay) lastOverlay.setMap(null);
}
```

Note that this doesn't remove the object, just hides it from showing on the map.  If you want to remove the overlay completely you should then also set it to null.

You can show them again - if you wanted to add a Redo button (in this case you wouldn't `pop` them as I have done). See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-remove for an example of how to implement this.

Updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3fe6nfdr/

Comment: thanks.But it completely removes the drawing ,is it possible to remove line by line?

Comment: @user7397787 You could do this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/delete-vertex-menu

Answer (score 1):

My above answer explains how to remove the most recent overlay entirely.

However to remove the most recently drawn line segment of a *polyline* you can store a reference to the shape object in the `overlaycomplete` event object:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
   overlays.push(event); // store reference to added overlay
});
```

Then using that determine if the object added was a *polyline*, grab the path array with `overlay.getpath()`, and finally call its `pop()` function to remove the last line segment:

```
// undo the last line segment of a polyline
function removeLineSegment() {

  var lastOverlay = overlays.length > 0 ? overlays[overlays.length - 1] : null;    

  if (lastOverlay && lastOverlay.type === "polyline") {
    var path = lastOverlay.overlay.getPath();
    path.pop(); // remove last line segment
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/q9xxt4kt/